Can there be more than two perfectly competitive markets in an economic system at the same time?
Can there be two or more distinct perfectly competitive markets in an economic system at the same time?

Perfect competition is a theoretical idealized construct. The question only really makes sense in the context of a specific model.

Logically, impossible. Because the cross-market flow of factors of production will make the prices of factors of production in each market tend to be the same, and finally lead to the same price of commodities in all markets, so that multiple markets become the same market.

How do a market for cars and a market for apples become the same market?

In theory, yes.
In reality, no.
Perhaps the best example is the (simplest kind of) DSGE model, in which goods, labor, and capital markets are all assumed to be perfectly competitive. And yes, perfect competition is assumed rather than derived, because as @MichealGreinecker comments, it is a theoretical construct, not a reality. So, as long as there are good reasons for making such an assumption (e.g. for tractability or simplicity) and that it does not lead to internal inconsistencies, you can have as many such markets in your model as you want.
